# Can you access a File browser thumbnail in a Django admin model class?

Tags: django, admin, thumbnails, file-browser

I have a Django application, with a model that has a Filebrowser field for uploading images. In the admin I have a method that returns an image html element so after a user uploads an image, they can see what they uploaded. Some images however are >10mb in size, and the page loads for a pretty long time. I tried looking through the File browser documentation to see if there was an attribute on File browser images that returns its thumbnail.

```
obj.filebrowser_img.thumbnail or obj.filebrowser_img.url_thumbnail
```

But I could only see ways to reference it in a Django template with fb_version template tags. Is it possible to retrieve the thumbnail version of the image outside of a template ?

Admin.py

```
class GalleryPhotoInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = GalleryPhoto

    readonly_fields = ('image_tag',)

    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('full-width',),
            'fields': ('name', 'image', 'image_tag', 'display_order', 'is_published')
        }),
    )

    def image_tag(self, obj):
        return u'<img src="{}" style="height: 125px;"></img>'.format(obj.image)

    image_tag.short_description = 'Image'
    image_tag.allow_tags = True
```

Gallery Photo model

```
class GalleryPhoto(models.Model):
    gallery = models.ForeignKey(PhotoGallery, null=True, blank=True, related_name='photos')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    image = FileBrowseField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Gallery Photo")

    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    display_order = models.IntegerField(default=99)
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Gallery Photo"

    def get_thumbnail(self):
        return self.image

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Gallery Photo"
        verbose_name_plural = "Gallery Photos"
        ordering = ("display_order",)
```

Comment: There's an example in the docs that matches what you're trying to accomplish: https://django-filebrowser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fieldswidgets.html#showing-thumbnail-in-the-changelist

Comment: Thanks xyres. I noticed that it references filebrowser's settings file, and the settings file from my project, django.conf.setting. Do I need to configure my settings files with a dictionary of formats ? It seems like thats already being done in Filebrowsers setting file, but nothing changes in the admin, now I just get a blank space.

Comment: I've no experience with django-filebrowser. I'm guessing you'll need to set [this setting](https://django-filebrowser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html#admin-thumbnail) in your settings file.